# getting list from scala object

Tags: scala, loops

I'm new to scala and I'm trying to get to construct a list from another one which I get from a scala object this is my model:

```
case class Session(
    _id: Option[String],
    participants: Option[Seq[Participant]])
  case class Participant(
    contact: Contact,
    participantStatus: Option[String])
```

Contact.scala

```
  case class Contact(
    firstName: Option[FirstName],
    lastName: Option[LastName],
    address: Option[Address])
```

Address.scala

```
  case class Address(
    email: Option[String])
```

using this loop:

```
for (s <- session.participants) println(s)
```

I get :

```
List(Participant(Contact(Some(FirstName(5m,Some(5),Some(5))),Some(LastName(5,Some(5),Some(5))),Some(Address(None,None,None,None,None,Some(5),Some(5),Some(5),Some(email1@gmail.com),None)),None,None),None), Participant(Contact(Some(FirstName(contact1,Some(contact1),Some(contact1))),Some(LastName(contact1,Some(contact1),Some(contact1))),Some(Address(None,None,None,None,None,Some(1),Some(1),Some(1),Some(email2@gmail.com),None)),None,None),None))
```

when I try : `println(s.contact)`
I get : `value contact is not a member of Seq[models.Session.Participant]`

Comment: could you give us the initialisation of your value session ? I have some code : for(s <- session.participants) s.map(s => println(s.contact)) but I cannot test it :p

Comment: it's working: Some(Address(None,None,None,None,None,Some(1),Some(1),Some(1),Some(email1@gmail.‌​com),None))  but now how can I access the email?

Comment: s.contact.address.email should do the trick ? But you should be careful with all those option and do some matching to see if it's there or not (this helped me when I was learning Options : http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html)

Comment: thank you so much, but when using println(s.contact.address.email)) I get the same error: value email is not a member of Seq[models.Address]

Comment: s.map(s => s.contact.address.map( a => println(a.email))), would that work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `s` variable is getting pulled out from `session.participants` which has type `Option[Seq[Participant]]`, so you get `Seq[Participant]`. If you want to loop through your participants, you need a list/seq, so:

```
val sessionParticipants = session.participants.getOrElse(Seq.empty)
for (s <- sessionParticipants) println(s)
```

Comment: You might want to change participants: Option[Seq[Participant]] into participants: Seq[Participant] a Option of a Seq is a little strange, since a Seq already has an Nullobject: the empty Seq

Comment: yes I see thank you very much for your help, another last thing: when using for (s <- sessionParticipants) println(s.contact.address) I get Some(Address(None,None,None,None,None,Some(1),Some(1),Some(1),Some(email1@gmail.com),None)) how can I get the email?

Comment: `val maybeEmail = s.contact.address.flatMap(_.email)` should be `Option[String]`. Then you can specify a fallback email with `getOrElse`, or, if you are 100% that every time you will have an email, you can call `get` on it... ;)